# In a C# Roslyn Analyzer, can I detect if a given Diagnostic is enabled?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm writing a Roslyn analyzer which detects certain patterns in the code that we don't like, and raising a Diagnostic (the specifics are irrelevant here).
However, detecting said patterns is potentially an expensive operation.

If a user has disabled the diagnostic using a `ruleset` file, using `NOWARN`, or other global/assembly level setting, is there a way that I can pick up on that inside my analyzer and use it in an `if` statement to avoid the potentially expensive parts?

I'm aware that I can put the diagnostic in it's own `class SomeNewAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer`, and the compiler won't run that analyzer if all diagnostics it supports are disabled, but is there way to do this as part of another Analyzer that raises multiple diagnostics?

Answer (score 1):

For future travelers: I did a lot more googling, and looked more deeply through the Roslyn API's that you have access to from within an Analyzer, and I'm fairly confident that in 2023, the answer is No. All signs suggest that if you want a given diagnostic to be turned off, that diagnostic should be in it's own Analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method in the DiagnosticDescriptor class which you can use:

```
public ReportDiagnostic GetEffectiveSeverity(CompilationOptions compilationOptions);
```

It returns ReportDiagnostic.Suppress if the rule is suppressed.

You can get the compilation options from your analysis context like this:

```
context.SemanticModel.Compilation.Options
```